# Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1, 3)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am new to machine learning and TensorFlow. I have followed some tutorials but this error "Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1, 3)" has overpass my current capabilities.

Let me first introduce the project in order to bring you more into context.

About the project:

1.I am trying to train a Neuronal Network to predict (approximate) the velocity distribution on an 
   elliptical pipe (this is only an illustrative example to show how machine learning tools such as 
   TensorFlow can be implemented in fluid dynamics).

2.The training and validation data are going to be generated using the analytical solution for steady 
   elliptic pipe flow in which the symmetry axes of the ellipse (a and b) and the velocity at the center 
   of the pipe are going to be used in order to determine the distribution of the velocity in the flow.

3. Input: 3 Skalars ------> Output: Matrix (nxn)

The testing data is generated with this part of the code:

```
#Coordinates
x_axis = np.arange(-10, 10.1, 0.1).tolist()
y_axis = x_axis

#Training data

start_time = time.time()

#Random vectors for the Axes of Symmetry for a General Ellipse
number_of_configurations = 2                                                    #The number_of_configuratios is to create multiple ellipses and generate more training data (it shall be bigger)
a_train = (np.random.rand(number_of_configurations, 1)*10) 
b_train = (np.random.rand(number_of_configurations, 1)*10)


#Analytical solution for a steady flow in a elliptical pipe (Langois, Deville, Chapter 5.2.1)
#Velicity component at the pipe center c = (a^2 * b^2)/(a^2 + b^2)              
c_train = (a_train**2 * b_train**2)/((a_train**2) + (b_train**2))

d_train = np.zeros(shape = [number_of_configurations,len(x_axis),len(y_axis)])  #For each configuration of the symmetry axes there is a len(x_axis) x len(y_axis) matrix with the velocity distribution

                                                        #This for loop generates the velocity distribution for each configuration of the symmetry axes  
for i in range(number_of_configurations):
  for j in range(len(x_axis)): 
    for k in range(len(y_axis)):  
      if ((x_axis[j]/a_train[i])**2) + ((y_axis[k]/b_train[i])**2) < 1: 
        d_train[i,j,k] = c_train[i] * ((1 - (x_axis[j] / a_train[i])** 2) - (y_axis[k] / b_train[i])** 2)  #Output data
      else: 
        d_train[i,j,k] = 0                                                      #Boundary contition "No slip"

#Input data
dataXtrain = np.concatenate((a_train, b_train, c_train), axis=1)
dataXtrain = np.reshape(dataXtrain, [number_of_configurations,1,3])             #Reshapes the tensor to a rank 3 tensor to match output data rank (I do not know if this is necessary)

end_time = time.time()
print('Running time: %f' % (end_time - start_time))

#The same code structure is going to be used to generate the validation and test data
```

Problem:

The error "Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1, 3)" and variations of it appear in the line 20 (history) on this part of my code:

```
#Neuronal network 
#Network Architecture
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    network = models.Sequential()
    network.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='random_normal', use_bias=False, input_dim=3))
    network.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='random_normal', use_bias=False))
    network.add(layers.Dense(5, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='random_normal', use_bias=False))
    network.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='random_normal', use_bias=False))
    network.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])


    # only save the model with the best validation loss value
    filepath = "\\Users\\carlo\\Desktop\\Seminar FDY\\Elliptic Pipe TF"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False,
                                 mode='min')
    # Training the model
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
    start_time = time.time()
    history = network.fit(dataXtrain, d_train, epochs=10000, batch_size=1, callbacks=callbacks_list,
                          validation_data=(dataXval, d_val), verbose=2)
    end_time = time.time()
    print('Training time %f' % (end_time - start_time))
```

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 15        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 25        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 25        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 20        
=================================================================
Total params: 85
Trainable params: 85
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I have tried to change the rank, size of my input data and also other activation functions with no result.

I really hope that someone can illustrate me in this matter. If required (and allowed) I can upload the whole code.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: After `network.compile()` add the line `print(network.summary())` and rerun your program. Then paste whatever is output by the line to this question.

Comment: Hello Björn. Thank you for your comment. I updated my question description with the 
required information.

Comment: In reshape, use `[number_of_configurations, 3]` instead of `[number_of_configurations,1,3]`. Or is there any reason you want the extra dimension in the middle?

Comment: Thanks @SusmitAgrawal. I have tried you suggestion but now I get the following (similar) error. `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 201, 201)` . I placed that extra dimension in order to match the structure of my output data.